# How to detect outliers with longitudinal data?

Tags: least-squares, outliers, random-effects-model, panel-data

I am running a pooled OLS and Random Effects (RE) model and I would like to test for whether there are any outliers.

I know how to do this for OLS, but I just dont know how to do it for Random Effects model?

If there is outliers when running pooled OLS does it mean that outliers are also present when running a Random Effects model?

And if there is outliers, what to do in RE?

Comment: IMO your question is a good fit for CV, but since the answer to your question is not really statistical (you already know how to do it for OLS) I will just re-direct you to the [lqmm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lqmm/index.html) and the [robustlmm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustlmm/index.html) packages (and the citations therein).

Comment: sorry, but I don´t get it - what is lgmm and robustlmm? and is it not a statistical question?

Comment: FYI, there are newish-tools for doing diagnostics for random effects models, eg HLMdiag.  See the paper "HLMdiag: A Suite of Diagnostics for Hierarchical Linear Models in R."